# Toggle html attribute contenteditable in php dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4

I found plenty of articles and solutions but for some reason my code still doesn't work. What am I missing?

Table: (creation works, important part is at the comment '! HERE')

```
<!-- Table with grades -->
<table class="table table-hover table-dark">
   <caption>List of grades</caption>
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Grade</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
      // fill table with data of database
      if($subject != '') {
        $query = "SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, u.username, s.subject, g.grade FROM tbl_grades as g INNER JOIN tbl_users as u on g.studentID = u.ID INNER JOIN tbl_subjects as s on g.subjectID = s.ID where s.subject = ? and classID = ? order by u.lastname";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $subject, $class);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result=$stmt->get_result();

        if($result->num_rows > 0) {
          $count = 0;
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            if(($count % 2) != 0) {
              echo '<tr class="bg-success">';
            } else {
              echo '<tr>';
            }
            echo '<th scope="row">' . ($count + 1) . '</th>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['firstname'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['lastname'] . '</td>';
            //! HERE
            echo '<td class="grade_td" contentEditable="false">' . $row['grade'] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            $count++;
          }
        }
        $result->free();
      }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn_edit">Edit List</button>
```

Toggle with javascript, jquery (multiple versions, none of them work):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // v1
  $('.btn_edit').click(function() {
    if($('.grade_td').contentEditable == false) {
      $('.grade_td').contentEditable = true;
    }
  });
  // v2
  $('.btn_edit').click(function() {
    $('td[contenteditable="false"]').contentEditable = true;
  });
  // v3
  $('.btn_edit').click(function() {
    $('.grade_td[contenteditable="false"]').contentEditable = true;
  });
  // more variations, same concepts
});
```

btw. the button event works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the jQuery `attr` function or set the attribute value on the element itself not the jQuery object.

```
$('.btn_edit').click(function() {
  
    $('.grade_td').attr('contenteditable', 'true') ;
  
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about custom attributes, but I would have made this a data attribute:

```
echo '<td class="grade_td" data-contenteditable="false">' . $row['grade']
```

and then referenced like this:

```
$('td.grade_td[data-contenteditable="false"]');
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp